# Read the auxiliary information of any database using wfdb

Tags: python-3.x

I need to read the auxiliary information (aux_note) of any database. How do I do it using python?

```
ann_ref= wfdb.rdann('mitbih/100', 'atr')
```

This shows only the labels and symbols.

Answer (score 0):

`ann_ref= wfdb.rdann('mitbih/100', 'atr')
print(ann_ref.aux_note)`

This is how its done.